# how to add hashlib++ library to visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, hashlib

I have recently downloaded the "hash lib++" library from it's own site.
but i have problems adding it to visual studio 2012 .I have tried adding it in additional include directories but it was not a successful attempt.I am new to c++ so if you could guide me in some way i would be thankful.

Comment: Can you please post exact error?

Comment: 1 IntelliSense: cannot open source file "hashlibpp.h"

Comment: It looks like it needs to be built from the sources in trunk/src. However the lib has a Makefile that looks like it is for gcc.

Comment: @user3092602 See my answer below. Option B

Answer (score 0):

A. If you are having compilation error for the functions defined in the library - then you have to include respective `header.h` file in your project.

B. If you are getting error header.h not found - then you have to provide include directories in

> Properties->C++->General->Additional include directories

C. If you are getting linker error for the functions defined in that library - then you have to include `libname.lib` in

`Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`

D. If you are getting `libname.lib` not found error - then you have to provide directory where lib is present in

`Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library directories`

Comment: yeah I'm getting the header not found one! but i have tried the way u mentioned it just didn't work .

Comment: @user3092602 So you have to add include directory there in C/C++ (not in linker). Make sure you give correct path there. For testing purpose you can give absolute path like C:\MyDrirve..\Include but change that to relative path later like ..\..\..\Include or using macro like $(ProjectDir)\Include